# Ошибка: не удаётся найти указанный файл

Tags: c#, visual-studio

При прохождении урока от Geekbrains быстрый шарп в С# на 4 уроке сталкнулся со следующей проблемой.
Необходимо было установить библиотеку small basic, сделать на неё связь, и записать код. Но при запуске программы появляется ошибка: не удаётся найти указанный файл.
В чем может быть проблема?

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: "Could not load file or assembly 'PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Не удается найти указанный файл."

```
using Microsoft.SmallBasic.Library;
namespace TurtleTraining;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Turtle.Move(100);
        Turtle.TurnRight();

        Turtle.Move(100);
        Turtle.TurnRight();

        Turtle.Move(100);
        Turtle.TurnRight();

        Turtle.Move(100);
        Turtle.TurnRight();
    }
}
```

Comment: А разве из текста ошибки не понятно, в чем проблема?

Comment: Не понятно, только начал изучать. Связь с библиотекой сделал.

Comment: Как исправить эту ошибку можно?

Comment: Версия дотнета у приложения какая? Подозреваю, что Framework 4.x вам нужен. Но лучше задайте этот вопрос куратору. Они вам библиотеки дают, они же и знают как ими пользоваться.

Comment: Дотнет - 6.0. Small basic - 1.2

Comment: Попробуйте Framework 4.7.2

Comment: SmallBasic - это очень древний компонент, последняя версия которого была выпущена в 2015г, а тогда еще не было .NET Core/.NET5-6, тогда был только .NET Framework, а значит и разрабатывать вам надо под него. Судя по [вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Small_Basic), была реализована поддержка только NET.Framework 4.5, вот его вам и надо брать за основу (хотя .NET FW новые версии должны поддерживать старые). Если поизучаете страницу курса, то увидите там уже [решение](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LyXz.png), удалять правда ничего не надо. А вообще, курсы 2016 года смотреть, ну такое...